# Debian 12 UEFI boot option erased after upgrading

Tags: debian, uefi, bios

I've installed a Debian 12 on my Dell Latitude 5470 laptop.
But I had to add a `UEFI` boot option in the bios to prevent the `No bootable device found` message.
I did as follow:

Reboot and press `F2` to enter the bios.

- Go to the `General` section then click `Boot Sequence`
- Make sure the `UEFI` option is checked.
- click the `Add Boot Option` button
- on the `Add Boot Option` panel click the `File Name` button
- Browse to the `shimx64.efi` file and click `Ok`
- Enter a name in the `Boot Option Name` field then click `Ok`.
- Save the changes and reboot

It works fine but the thing is now when I reboot after an upgrade (`sudo apt upgrade`) the UEFI option is erased (by grub I guess ?) and I get the `No bootable device found` again.
So I need to go to the bios and add the boot option again.

What can I do to prevent the boot option to be deleted ?

Comment: Have you updated to latest firmware available for your Dell? `sudo lshw | grep -m 1 -A 5 "*-firmware"` And compare to latest available on Dell site for your system.